# Could not find an image captured using raspistill on raspberry pi

Tags: raspicam

I ran the command
raspistill -o image.jpg

can someone tell me where is the image storred

Comment: it'd be in the "current directory" i.e. `./image.jpg` - did you run the command on the command line?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is no error and `raspistill` captures a picture then with your command the file you are looking for is in the same directory you are in. On the command line you can get this directory with:

```
pwd
```

and you can get the filename with:

```
ls -l image.jpg
```

If you want the full pathname to your image then use:

```
ls -d $PWD/image.jpg
```